# How can i sort a list of arrays inside a loop by a certain index inside every array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, sorting

Hello Im having problems trying to sort a certain object of arrays I have something like this

Okay heres a better example, im receiving a string from an ajax call and the string is something like this:

"name|price|blah|blah@name|price|blah|blah"

and im using the split function to split the string into two arrays by the delimiter @ and then splitting them again by the | (pipe) and as result I get the following:

and im looping through every value like this

```
 for(z = 0; z < actualarr.length; z++) {
   arr[1],
   arr[2]
   .....
 }


 ["name", "price", "blah" "blah"],
 ["name", "price", "blah" "blah"],
 ["name", "price", "blah" "blah"],
 ["name", "price", "blah" "blah"],
 ["name", "price", "blah" "blah"],
 ["name", "price", "blah" "blah"]
```

The problem is that they are inside a for loop and each array is an item, what im trying to do is sort the items by the value of "price" which is is in a certain index. Thanks!

Comment: this is not clear, can you provide an actual sample of this array

Comment: please add some realistic data and the result after "sorting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the array only outside of the generating of itself. Once you have the full array, you could sort it with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
var string = "foo|42|blah1|blah2@bar|17|blah3|blah4",
    array = string.split('@').map(function (s) { return s.split('|'); });
    
array.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.sort((x,y) => x[1] - y[1])
```

let 1 be your certain index and arr is your array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort